# Global variables for nested object classes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, oop, jquery

So i have the following structure in my js file:

```
var scrollingElements = {

    doc_height :    null,
    window_height : null,

    globalVar : {
        init: function() {
            //Get window and document initial heights
            this.doc_height     = $(document).height();
            this.window_height  = $(window).height();
        }
    },

    headerNav : {
        init: function(){
            console.log(this.doc_height);
        }
    },

    quickNavSidebar : {
        init: function(){
            console.log(this.doc_height);
        }
    }

}

$(function(){
    scrollingElements.globalVar.init();
    scrollingElements.headerNav.init();
    scrollingElements.quickNavSidebar.init();
});
```

However, this code doesn't work. `this.window_height` doesn't reach the right level in the object class. I'm unsure how to get to the higher level in order to store and access the global variables.  I think i need to do something like `this.parent()`, but obviously that doesn't work :/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use this inside the object to refer to the variables like you did. They are properties of the object and inside the object can be accessed directly.
This works for me:

```
var scrollingElements = {

    doc_height :    null,
    window_height : null,

    globalVar : {
        init: function() {
            //Get window and document initial heights
            doc_height     = $(document).height();
            window_height  = $(window).height();
            console.log(doc_height);
        }
    },

    headerNav : {
        init: function(){
            console.log(doc_height);
        }
    },

    quickNavSidebar : {
        init: function(){
            console.log(doc_height);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why it never occurred that they would be inherited is beyond me :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to save a reference to the enclosing class. Try reading a little about [Javascript closures](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/closures.shtml)

```
var scrollingElements = {

    doc_height :    null,
    window_height : null,
    that: this,

    globalVar : {
        init: function() {
            //Get window and document initial heights
            that.doc_height     = $(document).height();
            that.window_height  = $(window).height();
        }
    },

    headerNav : {
        init: function(){
            console.log(that.doc_height);
        }
    },

    quickNavSidebar : {
        init: function(){
            console.log(that.doc_height);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code gives an error: "that is not defined". I think you must use that when you are creating an object with a costructor function, not like this. in this case you cann access the property withouth specifying anything (inside the object, of course)